# How to implement install features option screen in Install4j?

Tags: java, install4j

I have few services in my application i.e.

1. Service A
2. Service B
3. Service C

While installing I want to give user the option to select which services he/she wants to install. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a form screen where you add 3 check boxes, one for each service. Let's say you set the variable names for the check box form components to "serviceA", "serviceB" and "serviceC".

Then you add 3 "Install a service" actions to the "Installation screen", one for each service. The condition expressions of the action for service A should be set to

```
context.getBooleanVariable("serviceA")
```

then it is coupled to the user selection. Add similar expressions to the other actions.